# Liferay link to another portlet with a specific action

Tags: java, liferay, portlet

I have a custom navigation portlet which includes links to several pages in my portal. Some of these links, though, are "submenu" options that are actually actions of a specific portlet. For instance, take a look at this image:

[image]

I have a portlet that displays a list of movies, and can also apply a filter by genre. Those links I've circled in my image should be links to the page with the Movie List portlet, but with a different action for each link.

How can I achieve that? I can only make actionURLs within a portlet, not for other portlets.

Answer (score 0):

You can create actionURLs to another portlet using the following tag provided by liferay and not by the portlet standard:

```
<liferay-portlet:actionURL plid="" portletName=""  />
```

where "plid" is the layout id of the page that the portlet is in and "portlet name" is the portlet id of the portlet that defines the actions that you want to call.

However, if the links you mention, apply filters to the movies list, then you could also do the filtering on page render and not necessarily using action processing.

Comment: How would you do that in the render phase?

Comment: You could pass parameters on the next render of the portlet that will specify the movie filtering that you want.
You will then catch these parameters with 

    ParamUtil.get...(renderRequest, "paramName")

and depending on its value filter the movies accordingly and display them.