# Liferay : How can we read form values from form when we redirect action one portlet to another portlet?

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-7, liferay-aui

**Example** 
There is two portlet : PortletA and PortletB

Now, I have one form in PortletA, When submit the form ActionURL redirect to PortletB. Now, I want to read all the form parameter in PortletB action method.

**Problem**

I got blank values in portletB because there is diffrent portlet-namespace. Please give me solution

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28715076/liferay-link-to-another-portlet-with-a-specific-action

Comment: On top of Daniele's suggestion: This sounds like an architectural issue: Typically portlets communicate through a well defined interface (events, public render parameters), and not through knowledge of each other's ids, namespace, forms. You may want to rethink the architecture, e.g. through sharing a common backend, where you can exchange persisted results of an action. Or use the standard inter-portlet-communication channels, as it's not quite sure that both portlets will always end up on the same page.